# Copying content from dev to live sites in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, migrate

We have several Drupal 6 sites. On most of the sites we will have some content editors, who will optimally log into a dev/test site and create content. Mostly just plain vanilla pages. What is the best method for migrating these newly created pages to the live server? I know there is the Deploy module and also Backup and Migrate. Are these the de facto standards? I was wondering if there is anything else I might be overlooking or if there is a better/easier solution. I am ONLY interested in moving content. We will be using GIT to move code and the Features module to migrate admin changes.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used node_export and recently I've found (in drupal 7) that the uuid module is invaluable. It means you can keep a track of content even if the nid's change as you move it over.

There are some legacy modules hanging around too that did an okay job but their functionality has really been surpassed by the modules you mention and the ones above.

If you're creating all your content using fields added with cck, you shouldn't have a problem. I personally use node_export along with features to allow easy importing and updating.

One gotcha you might want to look for on node_export is when importing on the new site, if a node is found with the same uuid (i.e. you're doing and update), the default is to create a new node. I prefer to create a new revision. Worth tracking down that setting (it's there in d7 so likely in d6 too).

EDIT: node_export doesn't currently export panels very well if at all - just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure and diversity of the nodes (how many fields of which type, how many node types). My first try would be to generate a view with XML output ([views_datasource.module](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) or [views_data_export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export)) on the dev site and use the [feeds.module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) for XML import on the live site.

The above XML export modules are avalable for D6 and D7. In Drupal 6 I used [views_bonus.module](https://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) for the XML export.